# How do you stop a thead background color from leaking when there are rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, html-table, rounded-corners

I have a table with rounded corners. I've specified a different background colour only for the `thead`.

On all browsers other than Firefox, the background colour leaks through the rounded corner. I've set `overflow` to `hidden` but that doesn't seem to help.

How can I stop the background colour from leaking through the rounded corner of the table?

Here's the code:
https://codepen.io/ayushn21/pen/OJVRMgG

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `border-radius` (***top-left*** and ***top-right***) for the appropriate `th` cells (***first and last child accordingly***). So simply add the following to the `CSS` of your [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/ayushn21/pen/OJVRMgG).

```
  th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Try it out in the snippet below.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #bcccdc;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 table td, table th {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 1px solid #bcccdc;
  border-top: 1px solid #bcccdc;
}
 table th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
 table th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
 table th {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f5f8;
  border-top: none;
}
 table td:first-child, table th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
 table tr.section-header {
  background-color: #eefcf5;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 500;
}
 table caption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>A caption</caption>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `border-top-left-radius:10px;` and `border-top-right-radius:10px;` to the first/last th cells.

You might also want to add `background-clip:padding-box;` to those cells, if it's still happening.

I found these tricks in this [CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table {
  tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  }
  tr:first-child th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 16px;
  }
}
```

You can do the same for last row:

```
table {
  tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
  }
  tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `cellspacing="0"` to `<table>` to remove the space between the table and cells. This will also solve your border radius issue with `<th>`:

```html
<table cellspacing="0"></table>
```